# JSCS line to long, when its not

Tags: javascript, jscs

I'm using JSCS with the airbnb preset (looked at switching to eslint for felt harder to get the style we wanted).

JSCS throw this error

```
    maximumLineLength: Line must be at most 100 characters at ./src/AbstractClient.es6 :
     1 |define(['underscore',
--------^
     2 |    'backbone',
     3 |    'som/models/Model',],
```

Line 1 is not more than 100 charaters, fact if I add a ')' to the line it stops complaining (starts complaing elsewhere).

I've googled and have not found anything like this. Currently, I have removed the line length check but would like to add it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the indentation of arrays is not excluded from the maximumLineLength,

More information found here:
https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/issues/424

For now, wrap your code with

```
// jscs:disable
... code here
// jscs:enable
```